# how to assign random choice to multiple choice question in kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I would like to built a multichoice app with kivy.
I created 3 buttons and bind each a popup saying right or wrong
However, I dont know how to random assign the right choice to one of the three buttons. at this moment, the right answer is always bind with button3

I tried using a random int (1,3), and depends on the random int, there are three sequence of self.add_widget. By each button, i also bind a function to change the text (which is next question)
but the problem is that i could not change the random int in the function binded with buttons

```
# for each button:
self.word.button1 = Button(text = 'answer1')
self.word.button1.bind(on_press=self.wrong)

self.word.button2 = Button(text='answer2')
self.word.button2.bind(on_press=self.wrong)

self.word.button3 = Button(text= 'answer3')
self.word.button3.bind(on_press=self.right)
```

I would like to know how to assign the right answer to a random button and also bind the right function

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use a list of buttons:

```py
self.buttons = [Button() for _ in range(3)]
correct_answer = random.randrange(len(self.buttons))
for i, button in enumerate(self.buttons):
    if i == correct_answer:
        button.text = "correct answer"
        button.bind(on_press=self.right)
    else:
        button.text = "wrong answer"
        button.bind(on_press=self.wrong)
```